# Sign in function not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've built an app that allows users to sign up, sign in, and sign out (my own devise from the ground up, if you will).

The app allows users to sign up, but when trying to sign in I get the following error:

// (needless to say I'm at a stand still, who ever can figure this out is a genius in they're own right)

## NoMethodError in SessionsController#create

```
undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: /Users/user/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app1

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

## Request

#### Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"/SEaqnrMf5X0pd4FVWbu8uWVAjTNw4LPKiXg+8Hl0PQ=",
"session"=>{"email"=>"Anthonypane@example.com",
"password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
"commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

Here are my Session_Controller Contents:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def new
@title = "Sign in"
end

def create
user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                        params[:session][:password])
if user.nil?
flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
@title - "Sign In"
render 'new'
else
sign_in user
redirect_to user
end
end   

def destroy
 sign_out
 redirect_to root_path
end
end
```

Users_Controller contents

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @title = @user.name 
 end

def new
@user = User.new
@title = "Sign up"
end

def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
sign_in @user
redirect_to @user, :flash =>  {:success => "Welcome to the Fun House!"}
else
@title = "Sign up"
 render 'new'
end
end
end
```

Sessions_helper contents

```
module SessionsHelper

 def sign_in(user)
cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
current_user = user
end

def current_user=(user)
@current_user = user
end

def current_user
 @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
end

def signed_in?
 !current_user.nil? 
end

def sign_out
 cookies.delete(:remember_token)
 self.current_user = nil
end 

private

def user_from_remember_token
 User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
end

def remember_token
 cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
end

end
```

And Lastly Users_helper contents:

```
module UsersHelper
def gravatar_for(user, options = { :size => 50})
gravatar_image_tag(user.email.downcase, :alt => user.name, 
                                        :class => 'gravatar',
                                        :gravatar => options)
end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this line:

```
@title - "Sign In"
```

Should be this:

```
@title = "Sign In"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, gave it a go, but still getting the same error.

Comment: "NoMethodError in SessionsController#create " is the error after having made the above changes from Ryan.

Comment: @Apane101: Show us the complete stacktrace for this new error. The error message itself won't do. Please do this in a ***new** question*

Comment: Kind of a newb to this, how do I go about finding the 'stacktrace' for this new error?

Comment: It will be in the same place as the old stack trace. Click "Full trace" on the page and it's the bunch of file references underneath that we want.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Here is the link to the full-trace posted as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845786/full-trace-for-nomethoderror