# Full Trace for NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stack-trace

This is essentially part 2. of my prior question, as requested I have created a new question due to the length of the code. Hope we can solve this, with your help I am sure that we can find a solution now with the new information.

Edit: Thanks for the input. here is the link to pt. 1 with the actual code: [Sign in function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822987/sign-in-function-not-working).

ps. Pls don't forget to vote this question up.

Heres the user.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  name               :string(255)
#  email              :string(255)
#  created_at         :datetime         not null
#  updated_at         :datetime         not null
#  encrypted_password :string(255)
#  salt               :string(255)
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor   :password
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, :presence => true,
                   :length => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length => { :within => 6..40 }

  before_save :encrypt_password

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypted(submitted_password)
  end

  class << self 
    def User.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
      user = find_by_email(email)
      (user && user.has_password?(submitted_password)) ? user : nil
    end

    def authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
      user = find_by_id(id)
      (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
    end
  end

  private

  def encrypt_password
    self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
  end

  def make_salt
    secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
  end

  def secure_hash(string)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
  end               

end
```

and the initial Full Trace:

```
undefined method `encrypted' for #<User:0x007fdcde331a90>

Rails.root: /Users/anthonypanepinto/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app1
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
app/models/user.rb:32:in `has_password?'
app/models/user.rb:38:in `authenticate'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__1623305808682769517__process_action__2997016911314885603__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3609576242730521204__call__105225653498443597__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"/SEaqnrMf5X0pd4FVWbu8uWVAjTNw4LPKiXg+8Hl0PQ=",
 "session"=>{"email"=>"#",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

Comment: A stacktrace isn't enough info, you'll want to add some code for people to help you. Also, your email address is in the stacktrace, not sure if you wanted that in there.

Comment: Let's see the user model. The stacktrace tells you where to start: `app/models/user.rb:32:in `has_password?'`

Comment: Sure, i've added the user.rb to body of the question.

Comment: Aside – crypto is hard. You shouldn't roll your own if you're not a specialist. Use something like bcrypt-ruby if you must, or Devise that handles all the user stuff for you:  https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby and https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that

```
def has_password?(submitted_password)
  encrypted_password == encrypted(submitted_password)
end
```

should be

```
def has_password?(submitted_password)
  encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end
```

---

More generally "how to read a stacktrace to solve a problem":

1) look at the top line of the stacktrace (the big wall of text)

```
activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
```

Is that a line in *your* code? in this instance no: it's from activemodel.

2) keep looking until you get to the first line of code that is for *your* code. In this case its:

```
app/models/user.rb:32:in `has_password?'
```

This is the line in *your* code that is causing the problem.

3) go look at the line of code that's causing the problem. The stacktrace tell us that this is line 32 of the file `app/models/user.rb`

In this case it's the middle line of these three lines:

```
def has_password?(submitted_password)
  encrypted_password == encrypted(submitted_password)
end
```

4) figure out what went wrong, by **reading the error message** ;)

the error message is telling you that "encrypted" does not exist as a method yes?

So look in your user model and see if you have a method called encrypted...

In this case you don't, but you do have one call "encrypt" - good chance that you've just accidentally typed "encrypted" instead of "encrypt"... fix that and you problem is solved.

These four steps can be used to solve most errors of this kind.

Comment: :-) That is the proper resolution. Thanks Taryn!

Comment: Hey @Apane101 - generally it's Good Form to accept an answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

seems like you ruby cannot identify your `encrypted` method for User object. you should be able to resolve this by including

```
require 'digest/sha1'
```

for your user model

Eg:

```
require 'digest/sha1'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #code
end
```

[read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128939/simple-encryption-in-ruby-without-external-gems) to understand more about encryption with out a gem